# Laplacian of the potential function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Given a potential function $$\Gamma(x)=\frac{1}{(n-2)|S^{n-1}||x|^{n-2}}$$
where $n\ge 3$ is an integer, $|S^{n-1}|$ is the volume of the sphere, $x$ is in $n$ dimension. Is it true that 
$$-\Delta \Gamma(x)=\delta_{0}(x)$$
where $\delta_0(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.

I am not sure if the constants are right, and I have the following try: Let operator $T_{\Gamma}:\phi \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Delta\Gamma(x)\phi(x)dx$. Where $\phi\in D(\mathbb{R})$ is a distribution. We obtain
$$\begin{align*}
T_{\Gamma}(\phi)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Delta\Gamma(x)\phi(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Gamma(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx\\&=\int_{B_{R}(0)}\Gamma(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{B_{R}(0)\backslash B_{\epsilon}(0)}\Gamma(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx
\end{align*}$$
where $R$ is a large constant, where $\phi(x)\equiv 0$ when $|x|>R$. This can be satisfied because $\phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$. But I got stuck here. I needs to prove that this equals $-\phi(0)$, but I do not know what to do next. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use
$$ \int_{B_R} \triangle \Gamma \phi \mathrm{d}x = \int_{B_R\setminus B_\epsilon} \triangle \Gamma \phi \mathrm{d}x + \int_{B_\epsilon} \triangle \Gamma \phi \mathrm{d}x $$
The first term in the domain of integration $\Gamma$ is smooth and $\triangle \Gamma = 0$ by computation, so you have that it goes to 0. For the second term we integrate by parts twice
$$ = - \int_{B_\epsilon} \nabla \Gamma \cdot \nabla \phi \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\partial B_\epsilon} \nabla \Gamma \cdot \vec{n} \phi \mathrm{d}\sigma = \int_{B_\epsilon} \Gamma \triangle \phi \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\partial B_\epsilon} \nabla \Gamma \cdot \vec{n} \phi - \Gamma \nabla \phi\cdot \vec{n}\mathrm{d}\sigma $$

Using that $\Gamma$ is locally integrable you have that as $\epsilon \to 0$ the only non-vanishing term is

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\partial B_\epsilon} \nabla \Gamma \cdot \vec{n} \phi \mathrm{d}x \tag{1}$$

evaluating 
$$\nabla \Gamma \cdot \vec{n} = \partial_r \Gamma = -\frac{1}{|S^{n-1}| |x|^{n-1}}$$

by continuity of $\phi$ we have that the expression (1) converges to $-\phi(0)$.

Comment: Why is $\Delta \Gamma$ zero? For instance, $\Delta \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}$

Comment: @Golbez: you compute: $\nabla 1/|\vec{x}|^s = -s \vec{x} / |\vec{x}|^{s+2}$ and so on, taking its divergence and noting that $\nabla \cdot \vec{x} = n$ where $n$ is the number of dimensions. . And why are you computing what you are computing in the previous comment? Your question states $n \geq 3$ and your comment considers the case $n = 2$...

Comment: Yes, you are right! I was lost in the computation .Thanks for your correction.

Comment: @WillieWang The last question is that is there a good way to prove that $\Gamma$ is locally integrable? Thank you .

Comment: Away from the singularity $\Gamma$ is smooth, hence bounded, hence locally Riemann integrable. Near the singularity you do the usual thing (that $1/r^{n-\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ is integrable near the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$). If you are not sure how to do it feel free to ask it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you! Is Jacobian needed for proving that it is locally integrable?

Comment: Okay, I know now, Using AM-GM we get $r^{n-\epsilon}\ge n (\prod_{i}x_i)^{\frac{n-\epsilon}{2n}}$ and done.