# Is it a dirac-delta?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Hoi, consider $\displaystyle u= \frac{1}{|x|}e^{-|x|}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$, then one can see
that $\Delta u = u$ for $|x|>0$ ( which one can see by transferring $u$ to spherical coordinates).

So can we then conclude: (*) $(1-\Delta)u$ is a distribution with support $= \left\{0\right\}$
and order $N=0$?

I want to either show that $((1-\Delta)u, \phi) = \phi(0)$ or show that (*) holds.

One of the 2 is enough to show that $(1-\Delta)u = \delta$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you see $u$ as a distritubtion, I mean, how do you define $(u,\phi)$? I am asking it, because $u$ is not even locally integrable.

Comment: I use it as $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}u\phi$. Apparantly  $cu$ with $c = 1/(4\pi)$ is the unique solution to $(1-\Delta)u= \delta$.

Comment: Your integral is not well defined. It can be $\infty$, so it not defines a distribution. You have to define in another way.

Comment: @DinkyDoe: You are right for every $\phi$ with $ 0\notin\operatorname{supp }\phi$ and for such $\phi$ the integral is well-defined. But with the general definition of $(u,\phi)$, the Dirac delta enters the formula ...

Comment: Thanks, however $(\delta, \phi) = \phi(0)$ and i would have to show the same: $((1-\Delta),\phi) = \phi(0)$ which is not so easy to see...So clearly $((1-\Delta),\phi) = \phi(0) =0$ holds true if $0\notin \text{supp} \ \phi$. So now what if $\phi(0)\neq 0$... why does then $((1-\Delta)u,\phi) = \phi(0)$ also hold true.

Comment: I have shown in previous excercises that if $u$ is a distribution with support = {0} and $u$ is of order $N=0$. Then $u = a \delta $ for some constant $a$.  (its not even trivial to me why $0$ is in the support of $(1-\Delta)u$ )

Comment: (first comment I meant ofcourse $((1-\Delta)u, \phi)=\phi(0))$)

Comment: Call it nonsence...$(1-\Delta)u = \delta$ holds true for the given $u$. Why i dont know yet. But i want to prove it. So $(1-\Delta)u$ must be a distribution. It is from Gerd-Grub: distributions and operators: Exercise 5.4b

Comment: Can't you just view it as a distribution for $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3 - \{0\})$ functions?  This function is locally integrable away from zero, so everything is well-defined then.

Comment: Sorry @DinkyDoe, I am doing wrong calculation, $u$ is locally integrable, so it's define a distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Side note for Tomás: $u$ *is* locally integrable, and therefore *is* a distribution).

Recall that $\Delta (|x|^{-1})=-4\pi\delta_0$ (if you don't know it already, see [Laplacian of the potential function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321477/)). Thus, if you can show that $\Delta (u -|x|^{-1}) = u$, the conclusion $(1-\Delta) u=-4\pi \delta_0$ will follow.

The function $u(x)-|x|^{-1} = (e^{-|x|}-1)|x|^{-1} = -1 + |x|/2+\dots$ is in $W^{2,1}$ locally, which implies that its distributional Laplacian is represented by its pointwise Laplacian. See [Calculation of the Laplacian of a function in $\mathbb R^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351165/).

Comment: You are right, i am doing wrong calculation.

Comment: OK, i know now why $\Delta(|x|^{-1}) = -4\pi\delta_0$ holds... but why what you say implies the desired conclusion I dont follow

Comment: I can prove both the statements you make...but I dont see yet why it implies what we want. Thnx if you can explain that.